# Model from view to controller comes null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajaxform

I have a Index view calling a partial view where I list my model (an IEnumerable) and draw checkboxes to select some of the items to update.

I wrapped the partial view with a ajax form, to send the model (with the checked check boxes), but when it reach to the controller action "Enviar", the custom object parameter comes null

I don't know why, according some posts my code should be working, please, what I'm doing wrong?

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<beDGRAIC.T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_Empresa>
.....
@Html.Partial("_ListaResumenCarga", Model)
.....
```

_ListaResumenCarga View

```
@model IEnumerable<beDGRAIC.T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Enviar", "Upload", new { @id = "FormCabecera" },
new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "SeccionListado",
    OnSuccess = "RefrescaListado"
}))
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Seleccionado, new { @checked = "checked" })</td>
                        <td class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Categoria)</td>
                        <td class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)</td>
                        <td class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nro_Registros)</td>
                    </tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Seleccionado)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id_Cuadro_Envio)
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

UploadController

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Enviar(IEnumerable<T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel> lT_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel)
    {
        ....
        return View("Envios", vT_Sedd_Envio_Empresa);
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public partial class T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel : BEPaginacion
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Seleccionado { get; set; }
    [DataMember]  
    public int Id_Cuadro_Envio { get; set; }  
    [DataMember]  
    public int Id_Envio_Empresa { get; set; }  
    [DataMember]  
    public string Categoria { get; set; }  
    .... // more properties
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and remove all the irrelevant code! The basic problem is you partial is generating duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes (so cannot bind to a collection). You need to use a `for` loop (the model needs to be `IList<beDGRAIC.T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_Empresa>`) or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_Empresa`. Then you have `EditorFor()` for `Seleccionado` followed by a `HiddenFor()` for the same property - even if you name the controls property it will only ever post back the original value, not the edited value.

Comment: binding to a collection is a pain. consider having a per line form instead

Comment: Thank you Stephen!, It worked!, the reason for post all my code was that I saw in other posts the users asked for that. If you want to, you can post your comment as answer to mark it as a solution... thank you very much

Comment: @culebrin, I have taken the liberty of removing most of the code in your question, keeping only what is relevant. Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you very much for that, but I have hard time to realize which part form my code was the relevant part of my error, that's why I decided put the hole code. Now I can analyze your edit to improve my future questions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use of a `foreach` loop in the partial is generating duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes meaning it cant be bound to a collection. You need to use a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel`. In addition you are generating a both a checkbox and a hidden input for property `Seleccionado`

EditorTemplate
`/Views/Shared/EditorTempplates/T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel.cshtml`

```
@model T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Seleccionado)</td> // do not set the checked attribute!
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id_Cuadro_Envio) // inside a td element
  </td>
  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Categoria)</td>
  .... // other properties to display/edit
</tr>
```

Then in the partial

```
@model IEnumerable<beDGRAIC.T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Enviar", "Upload", ....))
{
  <table>
   <thead>
     .... // table headings
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     @EditorFor(m => m) // this will render all the rows
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

Side notes:

1. A html helper binds to the value of a property (in you case `bool Categoria`) which mean that if the value of `Categoria` is `true`,
   the checkbox will be checked, otherwise it will unchecked. Do not
   try to set the `checked` attribute, and in any case it would not
   work because you have not used the overload correctly)
2. An `<input>` is not a valid child of a `<tr>` element
3. You have named you class `T_Sedd_Cuadro_Envio_EmpresaViewModel`
   suggesting its a view model, which clearly its not (before my edit
   it contained 17 properties, but you only use 6 in the view). A view model
   represents what you want to dislay/edit in a view - refer [What is a
   viewmodel in
   mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) (and please, keep it simple, just `EmpresaViewModel` and `public ActionResult Enviar(IEnumerable<EmpresaViewModel> model)`)